# display image in flutter app by fetching its name from server and load image from asset folder

Tags: flutter, flutter-image

I've only started programming with Flutter for a while, but I still have a lot to learn.
Now I wrote a small program with Flutter that shows the customer's shopping list
This program obtains the title of the payment gateway from the server database
Now I want every name of the payment gateway that is received from the server, its equivalent image is automatically called from inside the program asset folder and displayed to the user.

I have created this file with the name image.dart in which I have saved the path and image name of each payment method

```
class Images {
  static const String bKash = 'assets/images/bkash.png';
  static const String liqpay = 'assets/images/liqpay.png';
  static const String mercadopago = 'assets/images/mercadopago.png';
  static const String paymob = 'assets/images/paymob.png';
  static const String paystack = 'assets/images/paystack.png';
  static const String paytabs = 'assets/images/paytabs.png';
  static const String razorpay = 'assets/images/razorpay.png';
  static const String snangpay = 'assets/images/senang.png';
  static const String sslCommerz = 'assets/images/ssl_commerz.png';
  static const String stripe = 'assets/images/stripe.png';
  static const String flutterwave = 'assets/images/flutterwave.png';
  static const String fawryPay = 'assets/images/fawry_pay.png';
  static const String cod = 'assets/images/cod.png';
  static const String offlinePay = 'assets/images/offline_pay.png';
  static const String walletPay = 'assets/images/wallet_pay.png';
}
```

And I want the photo of each payment method to be recognized by its name and displayed to the user

For example, if the name of the payment gateway was "sslCommerz", it will find the path and name of the photo from inside this file and display its image as below.

```
SizedBox(
  width: 80.0,
  height: 80.0,
  child: FittedBox(
    child: Image.asset(
      **PaymentMethodImage**,
    ),
  ),
),
```

One way came to my mind, which of course is long and probably not very interesting in terms of programming like bellow:

```
if(paymentMethods!.bkash!)
PaymentMethodImage = Images.bKash;
if(paymentMethods!.liqpay!)
PaymentMethodImage = Images.liqpay;
if(paymentMethods!.mercadopago!)
PaymentMethodImage = Images.mercadopago;
if(paymentMethods!.paymobAccept!)
PaymentMethodImage = Images.paymob;
if(paymentMethods!.paystack!)
PaymentMethodImage = Images.paystack;
if(paymentMethods!.paytabs!)
PaymentMethodImage = Images.paytabs;
if(paymentMethods!.razorPay!)
PaymentMethodImage = Images.razorpay;
if(paymentMethods!.paypal!)
PaymentMethodImage = Images.paypal;
if(paymentMethods!.senangPay!)
PaymentMethodImage = Images.snangpay;
if(paymentMethods!.sslCommerzPayment!)
PaymentMethodImage = Images.sslCommerz;
if(paymentMethods!.stripe!)
PaymentMethodImage = Images.stripe;
if(paymentMethods!.flutterwave!)
PaymentMethodImage = Images.flutterwave;
if(paymentMethods!.fawryPay!)
PaymentMethodImage = Images.fawryPay;
```

Do you suggest a more suitable solution?

Answer (score 2):

a more efficient way is to have an `Map` instead of just writing a bunch of `if` statements

ie: in plain dart code
note: i would assume that the `paymentMethods.*` value is an enum

```dart
class Images {
  static const String bKash = 'assets/images/bkash.png';
  static const String liqpay = 'assets/images/liqpay.png';
  static const String mercadopago = 'assets/images/mercadopago.png';
  static const String paymob = 'assets/images/paymob.png';
  static const String paystack = 'assets/images/paystack.png';
  static const String paytabs = 'assets/images/paytabs.png';
  static const String razorpay = 'assets/images/razorpay.png';
  static const String snangpay = 'assets/images/senang.png';
  static const String sslCommerz = 'assets/images/ssl_commerz.png';
  static const String stripe = 'assets/images/stripe.png';
  static const String flutterwave = 'assets/images/flutterwave.png';
  static const String fawryPay = 'assets/images/fawry_pay.png';
  static const String cod = 'assets/images/cod.png';
  static const String offlinePay = 'assets/images/offline_pay.png';
  static const String walletPay = 'assets/images/wallet_pay.png';
}
enum PaymentMethod{
  bkash, 
  liqpay,
  mercadopago,
  paymob,
  paystack,
  paytabs,
  razorpay,
  snangpay,
  sslCommerz,
  stripe,
  flutterwave,
  fawryPay,
  cod,
  offlinePay,
  walletPay
}
final paymentMethodsToImagesMap = <PaymentMethod, String>{
  PaymentMethod.bkash: Images.bKash,
  PaymentMethod.liqpay: Images.liqpay,
  PaymentMethod.mercadopago: Images.mercadopago,
  PaymentMethod.paymob: Images.paymob,
  PaymentMethod.paystack: Images.paystack,
  PaymentMethod.paytabs: Images.paytabs,
  PaymentMethod.razorpay: Images.razorpay,
  PaymentMethod.snangpay: Images.snangpay,
  PaymentMethod.sslCommerz: Images.sslCommerz,
  PaymentMethod.stripe: Images.stripe,
  PaymentMethod.flutterwave: Images.flutterwave,
  PaymentMethod.fawryPay: Images.fawryPay,
  PaymentMethod.cod: Images.cod,
  PaymentMethod.offlinePay: Images.offlinePay,
  PaymentMethod.walletPay: Images.walletPay,
};
void main() {
// just hardcoding here, in your case this value comes from the Backend
final serverPaymentMethod = PaymentMethod.bkash;

// If for some reason the Backend sends a different payment provider which is not listed in the paymentMethodsToImagesMap, 
// we need to have a default image for that case

final paymentProviderImage = paymentMethodsToImagesMap[serverPaymentMethod] ?? 
Images.walletPay;

}
```

Comment: thanks alot afzal.i use your solution by a little change and it worked now like charm. :)